# Mount external HDD with writing permissions

Tags: mount, external-hdd, readonly

I'm using a **2.7T Porsche Design Desktop Drive** (external HDD) at work and I need to mount it on a **Proxmox 4.4-13** server. Currently I have several personal info but also have around 1TB free and the Proxmox server is running out of space. So after plug-in the disk to the server and execute **fdisk -l** the output is:

```
Device     Boot Start       End   Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdc1  *       63 732566645 732566583  2.7T  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

And the output for **blkid** is:

```
/dev/sdc1: LABEL="linux" UUID="2AB890F5B890C12D" TYPE="ntfs"
```

So far Proxmox is listing the external device with the identifier **sdc1**. Now I need to create a mount point for the external HDD. I won't use **/mnt/** because Proxmox has some relevant info already there. The directory will be created at **/home/** and the name will be **mountpoint** so:

```
mkdir mountpoint
```

The next steps show the process of mounting the device (**mount**) with **rw** permission, entering the mountpoint file (**cd**) and listing the files within (**ls**)

```
root@pve02:/home# mount -o rw /dev/sdc1 /home/mountpoint/
root@pve02:/home# cd mountpoint/
root@pve02:/home/mountpoint# ls
admin.jpg BackupsELEKA Pedro $RECYCLE.BIN System Volume Information
root@pve02:/home/mountpoint#
```

As the picture describes, the mount process was good, the ls command lists all the folder inside the external HDD. However when I try to create a folder (**mkdir**) or even create a file (**touch**) I got this:

```
root@pve02:/home/mountpoint# mkdir test
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘test’: Read-only file system
root@pve02:/home/mountpoint#
```

Then WHY? Didn't the option rw specify to allow **read** and **write** on the external disk? I have to say I tried to create folder and files inside a folder (Pedro and BackupsELEKA) and still nothing.

The thing is this should be a simple process to achieve, not a big deal, just like any other OS could do, why so difficult?

I'm posting this question after reading several posts such as:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/333287/external-hard-disk-read-only
and
https://askubuntu.com/questions/47538/how-to-make-read-only-file-system-writable

Comment: Don't post screenshots of text, paste the *actual text*.

Comment: I don't get why that could be a reason to downvote the post, still I will put the actual text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's an ntfs filesystem , so you must pass the right type of filesystem to the mount command

```
mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/sdc1 /home/mountpoint/
```

Comment: You should explain there is a performance impact to using that and why his original command didn't work.

Comment: After running that command I get: mount: unknown filesystem type 'ntfs-3g'

Comment: Looks like I don't have ntfs-3g installed, going out from work, will feed tomorrow the result after installing ntfs-3g

Comment: you don't have the ntfs-3g package already installed on your system.

Comment: I updated repositories then did apt-get install ntfs-3g. Finally mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/sdc1 /home/mountpoint as @D'ArcyNader suggested and now I can create directories inside the external drive.